# htaccess rule breaks css / js

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've created a simple htaccess rule to rewrite /jobs/24 to index.php?job=23

But for some reason this seem to break my entire website, none of my css rules or js files are applied anymore.

What can cause this problem?

I've looked around a lot, trying some different solutions, but nothing seems to work

Comment: Can you please post the code as well.

Comment: Would you mind providing us with the exact rewrite rules you're using?

Comment: My bad, sorry, this is the rule i used

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^jobs/([^/]+) index.php?job=$1 [NC]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your rewrite rule. Probably your simply addressing your css/js files not correctly.

Let me try to clarify what I mean with an example. Say your directory structure looks like this:

```
- index.php
- .htaccess
- js/
    - default.js
```

Now your including that JS file in your index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js"></script>
```

This will work if you call index.php directly - but if you call `jobs/24` and rewrite that to index.php, it won't. A rewrite isn't a redirection! The client doesn't know about it and still thinks that the requested file is in a directory `jobs`. This means that the browser will look for the default.js in the following place: `/jobs/js/default.js`

You can make use of absolute pathes to avoid such problems:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/default.js"></script>
```

Comment: That didn't help much.

In addition, I found that using the full url to the files helped

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your files cannot be found anymore, because everything is being rewritten. You can add exceptions for the files you need, or exclude a whole directory.

To exclude a whole directory just create the following `.htaccess` file in that folder:

```
rewriteEngine off
```

To exclude certain paths put this above your original `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(dir1¦dir2¦dir3) - [L]
```

You can test this using Firebug for example, the net tab shows you any file that couldnt be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rules also apply to the css and javascript urls. Have a look at those and see if they match the pattern in your rewrite rule. If they do, exclude them using a rewrite condition. [See the documentation for details.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)